# generate function based on keys of the dict

Tags: python-3.x

for a script created with prompt_tookit, I would like to add some services.
For this I need to create for each service a new function. I would like to generate this functions using the keys and values of dict since all the functions are almost the same.

This is my dict

```
services_dict={
'service_1':'apache2',
'service_2':'gdm.service',
'service_3':'ARLV',
'service_4':'ARLV_Frontend'}

for key,val in services_dict.items():
  def key():
     service_text_area.text='{}'.format(val)
```

It should generate functions like that:

```
def service_1():
   service_text_area.text='apache2'
def service_2():
   service_text_area.text='gdm.service'
```

Is there a way to this in python?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `prompt_tookit` package. Do they need to be functions? If so, have you considered a `lambda`? What is your use case for them?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you gave an example so I can apply it to how you would use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `exec` builtin to execute the function definition:

```
services_dict={
'service_1':'apache2',
'service_2':'gdm.service',
'service_3':'ARLV',
'service_4':'ARLV_Frontend'}

for key,val in services_dict.items():
  exec('def ' + key + '():\n' + '\tservice_text_area.text = "' + val + '"')
```